# Data transfer using Wi-Fi direct in Android devices

Tags: java, android, sockets, wifi, wifi-direct

I have implemented `Wi-Fi direct` in my code for multiplayer game. I am able to establish the connection between two Android devices as mentioned in Google documentation.

Then I have created 2 methods, for sending and receiving data for both client and server side. Now, I want to call these methods from my Renderer class, when I called these function it gives an NPE (Null Pointer Exception) for sockets and streams, but the same sockets and streams were used to establish the connection between two devices.

**Question:**

1. Is there any other way to transfer data using Wi-Fi direct?
2. How to fix the NPE when calling send/receive methods from my Renderer class?

**Code:**

Server Side:

```
public  class DataTransferAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
    ServerSocket serverSocket;


    Context context = mActivity.getApplicationContext();
    String s;
    InetAddress client_add;


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        if(first_call== 0) {
            try {
                first_call=1;
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9999);
                Log.e("hello", "Server: Socket opened");
                socket_server = serverSocket.accept();
                Log.e("hello", "Server: connection done");

                inputstream_server = new DataInputStream(socket_server.getInputStream());
                //  OutputStream outputStream = serverSocket.getO

                //getting data from client
                byte[] address = new byte[12];
                if (socket_server.isConnected())
                    inputstream_server.read(address);

                s = new String(address);
                String only_add = new String();
                only_add = s.substring(0, 12);

                client_add = InetAddress.getByName(only_add);

                Log.e("hello", "Server: clients ip 1 " + only_add);
                Log.e("hello", "Server: converted address 1 " + client_add + " \n is connected" +
                        socket_server.isConnected());

                Log.e("hello", "Server: clients ip " + socket_server.getInetAddress());
                Log.e("hello", "Server: client msg as address " + s);

                //client.connect(new InetSocketAddress(client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress(),9999),5000);


                dataOutputStream_server = new DataOutputStream(socket_server.getOutputStream());
                dataOutputStream_server.writeUTF("I am server");
                //dataOutputStream.flush();

                //  cancel(true);
                run_send_receive_server();


            } catch (IOException e) {

            }

        }
        return null;
    }


    //to transfer data to the another device
    public void send_data_server() {
        try {
            if (player_tap == 0)
                dataOutputStream_server.writeUTF("I am server");
            } catch (IOException e) {

        }

    }

    //to receive data from the another device
    public void received_data_server() {

        try {
            byte[] address = new byte[12];
            inputstream_server.read(address);

            String s = new String(address);
            Log.e("in server", " in server received : " + s);
                            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

    }

    public void run_send_receive_server() {

        send_data_server();
        received_data_server();

    }
```

Client Side:

```
public class DataTransfer extends IntentService {

int socket_timeout = 5000;
public  static String group_owner_address = "go_owner";
public  static String group_owner_port = "go_port";
public  static String action_send_data = "com";
DataOutputStream outputstream_client;
DataInputStream inputstream_client;
ModelRenderer modelRenderer;
Socket socket_client;
public  DataTransfer(String name){
    super(name);
}
public DataTransfer(){
    super("hello");
}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


        Log.e("hello", "client socket");
        Toast.makeText(this, "client socket", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (intent.getAction().equals(action_send_data)) {
            String host = intent.getStringExtra(group_owner_address);
            socket_client = new Socket();
            int port = intent.getIntExtra(group_owner_port, 9999);

            //binding connection
            try {
                Log.e("hello", "opening client socket");
                byte[] address = getLocalAddress();
                String ipAdd = getDottedDecimalIP(address);

                socket_client.bind(null);
                socket_client.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), socket_timeout);

                Log.e("hello", "device socket address " + socket_client.getInetAddress());


                Log.e("hello", "client socket is connected" + socket_client.isConnected());
                Log.e("hello", "device address  :" + ipAdd + "  byte " + address);

                //sending data to server
                outputstream_client = new DataOutputStream(socket_client.getOutputStream());
                outputstream_client.write(ipAdd.getBytes());


                //getting data from the server(supposed to)

                inputstream_client = new DataInputStream(socket_client.getInputStream());

                byte[] address_to_sto_fr_ser = new byte[13];
                inputstream_client.read(address_to_sto_fr_ser);

                String s = new String(address_to_sto_fr_ser);
                Log.e("msg from server", "msg from server " + s);

                outputstream_client.flush();

                run_send_receive_client();
                //  stream.close();
                //  is.close();


            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        }

}

public void run_send_receive_client(){

    send_data_client();
    receive_data_client();

}




public void send_data_client(){
    try {
        String s = "hello";
        String value = "True";
                       outputstream_client.write(s.getBytes());

        }
               }
    catch(IOException e){
    }

}

public void receive_data_client() {
    byte[] address_to_sto_fr_ser = new byte[13];

    try {
        if(inputstream_client!=null) {
            inputstream_client.read(address_to_sto_fr_ser);
        }            String s = new String(address_to_sto_fr_ser);
        Log.e("in"," in receive data: " + s);
                }catch (IOException e){

    }

}


private byte[] getLocalAddress() {

    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    if (inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address) {
                        // fix for Galaxy Nexus. IPv4 is easy to use :-)
                        //  Log.e("hello","hello : "+ Arrays.toString(inetAddress.getAddress()));
                        return inetAddress.getAddress();
                    }
                    //return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString(); // Galaxy Nexus returns IPv6
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        //Log.e("AndroidNetworkAddressFactory", "getLocalIPAddress()", ex);
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        //Log.e("AndroidNetworkAddressFactory", "getLocalIPAddress()", ex);
    }
    return null;
}

private String getDottedDecimalIP(byte[] ipAddr) {
    //convert to dotted decimal notation:
    String ipAddrStr = "";
    for (int i=0; i<ipAddr.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            ipAddrStr += ".";
        }
        ipAddrStr += ipAddr[i]&0xFF;
    }
    return ipAddrStr;
}
}
```

**Log cat:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at com.octane.pingpong.DataTransfer.send_data_client    (DataTransfer.java:110)
                  at com.octane.pingpong.DataTransfer.run_send_receive_client(DataTransfer.java:95)
                  at com.octane.pingpong.ModelRenderer.Tap_To_Cont_Ingame_Logic_Multiplayer(ModelRenderer.java:3929)
                  at com.octane.pingpong.ModelRenderer$SampleOnClickListener.onClick(ModelRenderer.java:4157)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17620)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please tell the code that gives the `NullPointerException`. Which pointer is null? Don't use a pointer if it is null. Check for null before use. You do that sometimes already. For `inputstream_client`. Why not for `outputstream_client` too?

Comment: Indeed for data transfer you have to use the same socket as used to connect. But Are you?

Comment: `public void send_data_client()`. Why don't you make that `public boolean send_data_client()`? Then the caller can check the return value and know if sending succeeded.

Comment: @greenapps Yes, I am using the same socket for transfer, but it shows NULL when I tried to access it from the Renderer class.

Comment: Talking in this way will not help very much.

Comment: @greenapps When I tried to access the send_receive_server/client() method form the Renderer class, it gives me NPE. NOW, I have made the sockets and all streams 'static', so it is not throwing NPE. Now, it is throwing NetworkOnMainThreadException only when I tried to call receive method. When I called send_data_client/server() method it is working, but if I called received_data_clent/server() method it throws   NetworkOnMainThreadException . So, how should I run received method continuously in the background thread?

Comment: All network code/actions must be executed in a thread or AsyncTask to prevent a NetworkOnMainThread exception.